# How to download file from firebase storage url to internal storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-download-manager

I want to download the pdf file from URL, I'm unable to download it shows  Unsupported path. how to set the correct path.

```
 public void downloadAndOpenPdf(String url){

        String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url.length());
        file = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), fileName);

            if(!file.isFile()) {
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                req.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));
               // req.setTitle("Some title");

                BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        unregisterReceiver(this);
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            openPdfDocument(file);
                        }
                    }
                };
                registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                        DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
                dm.enqueue(req);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Download started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                openPdfDocument(file);
            }
        }

        public boolean openPdfDocument(File file) {
            Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            target.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
            target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            try {
                startActivity(target);
                return true;
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this,"No PDF reader found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: `Environment.getDataDirectory()` – That's likely the issue. `DownloadManager` won't have write access there. Is that really where you meant to try to save that download?

Comment: Refer this link to get a child node and directory from firebase http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/01/android-firebase-file-storage-part-2.html

Comment: please post stack trace along with question.

Answer (score 2):

if you're downloading files from firebase storage try this code

```
private void getFileUrl(){
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("your file name as is from firebase storage");
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
        String url = uri.toString();
        downloadFile(getContext(), "your file name", "file extension", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
        mProgressBar.hide();
    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        mProgressBar.hide();
        ToastUtil.toastLong(getContext(), "something went wrong " + e.getMessage());
    });
}


private void downloadFile(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url) {

    DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);

    downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
}
```

let me know if it works.

Comment: E/UncaughtException: java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/2017%20Fall%2F1st-Semester_Fall-2017.pdf

Comment: i want ot download pdf file from url and save into internal storage's download folder

Comment: data/2017%20Fall%2F1st-Semester_Fall-2017.pdf  is this the path form your device or is it from firebase storage? it looks like its from your device

Comment: `StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("your file name as is from firebase storage");` in this line pass the file name present in firebase storage  you want to download.

Comment: can you give me your email?